# Fedora 37 kernel config change tool

Tags: kernel, config, fedora

Fedora 37 has some sort of a strict format for its kernel config file via its fedpkg compilation way. I.e. all options must be present, whether set or not, maybe other formatting.

If you try to change the default config via nconfig and then use that file it throws an error. If you change options in situ by editing the supplied kernel-x86_64-fedora.config file it compiles fine.

Question - what's a GUI way to change Fedora's kernel config file?

Answer (score 0):

A solution to this is to:

1. `fedpkg clone -a kernel --branch f37 --depth 1`
2. `cd kernel`
3. `fedpkg prep` (this will fetch the kernel source and unpack it)
4. `cp kernel-x86_64-fedora.config kernel-6.0-*/linux-6.0*/.config`
5. `make nconfig`
6. save without changing anything to .configdefault
7. make changes in the nconfig gui
8. save with changes to .config
9. `diff -u .configdefault .config | grep -E "^\+" > .configchange`
10. `sed 's/[+]//g' .configchange | sed -e '1d' > kernel-local`
11. `cp kernel-local ../../`

This catches additions to the default kernel config and saves them to kernel-local file in kernel folder. `fedpkg local --without debug --without debuginfo --without doc --without cross_headers --without perf --without tools --without bpftool --with verbose --with up --without configchecks` then parses kernel-local and merges it into the kernel build. This is a nice way for Fedora to keep custom kernel configuration separate from the vanilla config and for an end-user to have a clean delta at hand.